# How can I set up an email discussion list based on CiviCRM groups?

Tags: email, groups, mailing, google

Is it possible to create civicrm integrated email discussion lists? For example I want the members of a civicrm group to be able to send an email to theirgroupname@ourcompany.org and have it sent to all members of the group. All members of the group should be able to respond to such messages. Email version of google groups, yahoo groups. I did some googling and saw some mentions of Drupal/Civicrm/Organic Groups/Mailman integration but can't tell what is the current best solution. A lot of the pages were very old.

Comment: Will be using Drupal if we end up using CiviCRM.

Comment: Found this: https://civicrm.org/extensions/google-groups-civicrm-integration/12       We are currently using google groups, so this might work for us, if it automates the process of keeping civicrm groups synchronized with google groups. Anyone able to comment on how well it works?

Comment: Get in touch if you end up needing to look further at Mailman, we have deployed this in a couple of situations including making a UI that let's you set the Civi Group, or a Civi Relationship, as the basis for the Mailman group. There is still the issue about what happens when someone unsubs via Mailman, since the Civi synch just puts them back in ;-)

Comment: I would definitely be interested in learning more about this. Thanks!

Comment: @CynthiaWoodard we funded that one and are using it currently. Works fine! Setup is a bit long-winded, admittedly, but fine after that.

Comment: @andrew - should we compare notes? peter.davis@fuzion.co.nz. not sure what you are referring to but sounds like there may be 2 projects on the go

Comment: @petednz-fuzion sorry - I meant the Google Groups Sync extension (phone app makes it look like I can reply to particular comments).

Comment: @petednz-fuzion Is this Civi->Mailman something you could share?  I'm interested in that exact setup too.

Comment: I don't think we were ever able to take it further than a build for that single client ie it didn't not get developed as an extension or even a releasable module. i will check what might be involved in making it able to be shared.

Comment: @petednz-fuzion it would be great if you could post your comment about Mailman as an answer, since it seems to best answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

we have deployed this in a couple of situations including making a UI that let's you set the Civi Group, or a Civi Relationship, as the basis for the Mailman group. There is still the issue about what happens when someone unsubs via Mailman, since the Civi synch just puts them back in ;-)

I don't think we were ever able to take it further than a build for that single client ie it didn't not get developed as an extension or even a releasable module. i should check what might be involved in making it able to be shared.